How can I properly ground my service disconnect panel?
I am not sure my house is properly grounded.
The meter outside connects to a single breaker panel with a 150 amp breaker (I will call this the service panel). This service panel is not connected to any ground wires.
The service panel connects to my house's breaker panel (only one). The house breaker panel is connected to a 6 AWG bare copper wire that exits the house underground, alongside the gas main. From there, I cannot tell if it is connected to a ground rod, or simply bonded to the gas main or meter. There is a second bare copper wire connected to that, which connects to some long ago disconnected copper pipe (it looks like this copper pipe might have provided an outdoor spigot many years ago, but the house was remodeled by a previous owner to build an addition there, so the spigot line was disconnected).
With that uncertainty, I was thinking of installing two ground rods outside, at least 8 feet apart. Then a continuous run of #4 AWG bare copper wire would run from the first rod, to the second rod, and then into the house.
Which breaker panel should this ground wire connect to? Should I add another ground wire from one panel to the other as well?

There are two separate issues here:
Where should the ground wire originate from in your electrical system?
Generally speaking, this traditionally has been "first thing past the meter." However, many houses now have a service disconnect before any actual panel. In that case, the disconnect is usually only a disconnect and the ground is done to the first "real" panel.
Code has changed in the last several years to require an outside disconnect. That can be similar to what you have, but it is also often done as a small panel either with the meter ("meter main") or next to the meter. In those cases the ground can go to that small panel but, depending on what is connected to the panel (besides the main feed to a big panel elsewhere) it is possible that the ground would go the big panel elsewhere, making that big panel the true main panel.
A key rule though is that wherever the ground starts is the main panel, and in the main panel neutral and ground are bonded and in any other panels they are not bonded.
In your case, all indications, including the existing ground wires, are that the big panel is the true main panel and that is where your new ground wires should go.
What do I connect the ground wire to?
There are three main things you can do with a ground wire:

Ground Rod(s)

One or two ground rods, several feet apart if there are two of them. If ground rods are the only thing then a test is often required to check how good the ground is. But the test is only needed if there is only one ground rod and putting in a second ground rod is easier than running the test. So if it is only ground rod(s), two of them.

Water Pipe

This is the old way of doing things. Some jurisdictions still require it and/or allow it instead of one of the ground rods. The problem, as you found, is that if the wire doesn't go all the way to the plumbing entrance then it is easy for pipe in between the entrance and the ground connection to be replaced with plastic pipe or disconnected altogether, making the ground connection useless. In my house when I had a heavy-up done, the electrician (I helped) ran a ground wire to the plumbing entrance, bonded (to play it safe and make sure the inspector would be OK with it) both before and after the initial shutoff valve. At some later time when disconnecting the old panels we found the old ground wire going to copper pipe elsewhere in the house, but a long distance from the entrance. We never did find the old ground rod.

Ufer Ground

This is basically a ground embedded in concrete when pouring the foundation. It is required in many places for new construction and is considered even better than ground rods.
For a retrofit/repair situation, Ufer is normally not an option. It sounds like you originally had one rod plus water pipe. That may or may not still be the rule in your jurisdiction. Check with a local electrician and/or the electric permitting department to find out what they currently require. And then install that.
As I understand it, 4 AWG is required for 200A service. Your existing 6 AWG may be adequate for 150A service, which is what you have based on the disconnect. But running 4 AWG now will mean if you ever upgrade to 200A service then you won't have to replace the ground wire(s).

Currently the NEC requires a disconnect outside the building. It must be labeled Suitable For Use As Service Equipment. If it is marked Suitable For Use As Service Equipment Only then it must be your service panel. If isn't marked "only" then you can leave the neutral not bonded to ground at the disconnect and affix a label that says:

METER DISCONNECT NOT SERVICE EQUIPMENT

and then the feeder can continue to another panel serving as the Service where the neutral is bonded to the panel ground. This then becomes the connection point for all grounding electrodes.
Since you can't identify adequate grounding electrodes you certainly should add ground rods. Using #4 copper is fine, but NEC 250.66(A) allows it to be #6 for ground rods if the conductor does not extend to another electrode type that requires a larger size.

250.66 Size of Alternating-Current Grounding Electrode Conductor Diagram The size of the grounding electrode conductor and bonding
jumper(s) for connection of grounding electrodes shall not be smaller
than given in Table 250.66, except as permitted in 250.66(A) through
(C).
(A) Connections to a Rod, Pipe, or Plate Electrode(s) If the >grounding
electrode conductor or bonding jumper connected to a single or
multiple rod, pipe, or plate electrode(s), or any combination thereof,
as described in 250.52(A)(5) or (A)(7), does not extend on to other
types of electrodes that require a larger size conductor, the
grounding electrode conductor shall not be required to be larger than
6 AWG copper wire or 4 AWG aluminum or copper-clad aluminum wire


As I understand table 250.66 combined with standard ampacity charts, 150A (current service size based on the disconnect) would use 1 copper or 2/0 aluminum (using the standard 83%) and therefore 6 AWG ground (as exists) but 200A would need 2/0 copper or 4/0 aluminum and therefore 4 AWG. Hence my point of "4 AWG is a good idea to allow for future heavy-up to a now-standard 200A service".

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I added full text from below table 250.66(A). Similar language exists allowing max size of #4 copper for Ufer grounds in 260.66(B)
